# Assistance with my http endpoint URL for AWS Kinesis - Firehose API

Tags: api, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I think I am able to create an API HTTP endpoint but when I sent it for testing, the other person says it is not discoverable. I followed the instructions in the https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/stream-data-to-an-http-endpoint-with-amazon-kinesis-data-firehose/ but seems still not working.

I used api.namehttpendpoint.com.

To give you an overview, I am trying to accomplish for my class project:

Data will come from emfit devices. All data will be collected with AWS kinesis and firehose and will be sent to analytics. This may look simple but I am new to the platform and realizing the complexity or maybe not of the AWS platform with regards to what I need to accomplish.Any help will be greatly appreciated.